# How do I email a report automatically oh the 1st day of each month?

Tags: drupal, user

I want to sent multiple reports (group membership lists) to different individuals (the co-ordinator of each group) on the 1st day of each month.  Scheduled jobs only allows hourly or daily mailing (not monthly) so I believe I may have to use CiviRules, but can I trigger a rule for a specific day of the month?  We use Civi with Drupal.

Comment: Please let me know the version of Civicrm you are using? - also please check the latest version - monthly, yearly are available

Comment: Hi Ramesh,  we are currently on Civi 4.6.21, which is being hosted for us.

Comment: Are you planning for an upgrade - which will fix the issue else as Jon said try Flexible Jobs extension - I guess this helps

Comment: Thanks Ramesh.  I'll contact the company hosing our site about both the sugestions.

Answer (score 5):

Ramesh's comment is correct.  The best overall solution is most likely to upgrade to CiviCRM 4.7, which adds a "Monthly" option.

If upgrading is not an option and you're on CiviCRM 4.6, you can install the [Flexible Jobs](https://civicrm.org/extensions/flexible-jobs) extension to get this functionality.